# Swift - Obj C Interoperability with Closures / Blocks

Tags: objective-c, swift, objective-c-blocks

Im trying to import a swift class into my Obj C project. Everything is working but im trying to convert this Swift Closure statement to OBJ C. I believe it would be a Block in obj c but i just cant seem to get it, any help would be greatly appreciated !

Swift Declaration:
    `public var otpEnteredString :((String)->())?`

Swift Use in View Controller:

```
    ObjectName.otpEnteredString = { pin in
    NSLog("The entered pin is %@",pin);
}
```

in Obj C im trying to do

```
    [ObjectName otpEnteredString:^(NSString *pin){
    NSLog(@"The entered pin is %@",pin);
}];
```

but i get the standard "No visible interface declares the selector ..
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

i can see the declaration in xcode but im not entirely sure how to translate that to obj c

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
ObjectName.otpEnteredString = ^(NSString *pin){
    NSLog(@"The entered pin is %@",pin);
};
```

Or this:

```
[ObjectName setOtpEnteredString:^(NSString *pin){
    NSLog(@"The entered pin is %@",pin);
}];
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I knew i was close but it was killing me !

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
@objc
public var optEnteredString : ((String) -> ())?
```